# Windows 10 PhoneCallOriginManager extension

Tags: c#, .net, windows, mobile, win-universal-app

I'm trying to build an app for Windows 10 Mobile that would act as the default phone call origin manager application. For this to be possible, the user must pick this application in the settings, as there can be only one ([source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows.applicationmodel.calls.provider.phonecalloriginmanager.showphonecalloriginsettingsui)).

I've checked the sample made exactly for this scenario ([sample on Github](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CallerID)).

The problem is, that in the [.appxmanifest](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/CallerID/cs/Package.appxmanifest) file, an extension must be declared for our application to show up in the settings dialog, when selecting the default phone call origin manager app, specifically line [39](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/CallerID/cs/Package.appxmanifest#L39).

The error message I get is:

> The element 'Extensions' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10' has invalid child element 'Extension' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/mobile/windows10'. List of possible elements expected: 'ApplicationExtensionChoice' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10' as well as 'Extension' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10' as well as 'Extension' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10'.

I've been looking for the cause of this, and even came across this posted [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/issues/286) but I do not believe that answer is correct.

Am I missing something obvious here or is this a problem with the framework itself?

Comment: Also find other post asking the same problem. The error message is saying the XML namespace (mobile:) is unexpected. Try to change line 39 from `<mobile:Extension...` to `<Extension`  or `<uap:Extension...`, does it work?

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce this issue in Visual Studio 2015 update 1, but the sample works well without any problem.

In my mind it may be the incompatibility issue between the manifest file and designer. And I have reported this issue to Microsoft using the internal channel.

Because this is only a visual studio designer issue and the app itself will not be impacted, I think we can simply ignore this issue until a fix is available.

Thanks.

Comment: So it's currently not possible to actually develop an app that can be registered as the default phone call origin manager? Or is there a possible workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

A addition for the answer of Fang Peng, in order to ignore this issue, in your appxmanifest xml file, you need add this information:
IgnorableNamespaces="your_ignore_name_space" in the  tag, for example:

```
<Package  ... xmlns:mp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/phone/manifest"IgnorableNamespaces="mp">
```